# не срабатывает функция выхода из профиля в django

Tags: python, django, logout

Как я понял не очищаются куки, поэтому пользователь даже после выхода остается авторизованным. Как только почистишь куки вручную в браузере пользователь розлогинивается, вот класс который отвечает за выход

class LogoutView(RedirectURLMixin, TemplateView):
"""
Log out the user and display the 'You are logged out' message.
"""

```
http_method_names = ["get", "options"]
template_name = "registration/logged_out.html"
extra_context = None

@method_decorator(csrf_protect)
@method_decorator(never_cache)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """Logout may be done via POST."""
    auth_logout(request)
    redirect_to = self.get_success_url()
    if redirect_to != request.get_full_path():
        # Redirect to target page once the session has been cleared.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_default_redirect_url(self):
    """Return the default redirect URL."""
    if self.next_page:
        return resolve_url(self.next_page)
    elif settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL:
        return resolve_url(settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL)
    else:
        return self.request.path

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    current_site = get_current_site(self.request)
    context.update(
        {
            "site": current_site,
            "site_name": current_site.name,
            "title": _("Logged out"),
            "subtitle": None,
            **(self.extra_context or {}),
        }
    )
    return context
```

Comment: Как именно пользователь отправляет запрос в этот класс?